# Login system in C++ not working

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I'm trying to debug my c++ login system that does not seem to be working (i.e. it says wrong user ID and password even on entering the right user ID and password).
Registering stores the login details in a binary file while login reads that file (ID.dat) and checks for a match.
This is my high school project and I really need to fix this on time. I've been trying to do that for a really, really long time. Please point out the possible errors. Thank you for your help.

Edit: I've added the new functions but it doesn't seem to work

```
//Class for storing IDs
char Level;
class ID
{
    public:
    char username[20],pass1[20],pass2[20],IDtype,systemID[5];
    int checkuser(char u[20])
    {
        return(strncmp(u,username,strlen(u)));
    }
    int checkpass(char p[20])
    {
        return(strncmp(p,pass1,strlen(p)));
    }
};

//Registration function
void IDregister()
{
    clrscr();
    ID i;
    ofstream fout;  
    fout.open("ID.dat",ios::app);
    gotoxy(30,6);
    cout<<"*--- Register ---*";
    gotoxy(25,9);
    cout<<" Enter User ID - ";
    fgets(i.username,21,stdin);
    gotoxy(25,11);
    cout<<" Enter Password - ";
    fgets(i.pass1,21,stdin);
    do
    {
        cout<<"\n           Re-enter Password - ";
        fgets(i.pass2,21,stdin);
    }while(strncmp(i.pass1,i.pass2,strlen(i.pass1))!=0);
    cout<<"\n       To register as Admin, type system ID below.\n            Else press Enter ";
    fgets(i.systemID,6,stdin);
    if(strncmp(i.systemID,"#123#",5)==0)
        i.IDtype='A';
    else
        i.IDtype='U';
    fout.write((char*)&i,sizeof(i));
    cout<<i.IDtype;
    getch();
    fout.close();
    IDlogin();
}

//Log-in Function
void IDlogin()
{
    clrscr();
    int flag=1;
    ID acc;
    char usercheck[20],passcheck[20];
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("ID.dat",ios::in);
    gotoxy(30,7);
    cout<<"*--- Log-in ---*";
    gotoxy(25,10);
    cout<<"Enter User ID - ";
    fgets(usercheck,21,stdin);
    gotoxy(25,12);
    cout<<"Enter Password - ";
    fgets(passcheck,21,stdin);
    gotoxy(25,14);
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        fin.read((char*)&acc,sizeof(acc));
        if(acc.checkuser(usercheck)==0&&acc.checkpass(passcheck)==0)
            flag=0;
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        cout<<"Logged in successfully!";
        Level=acc.IDtype;
        getch();
        mainscreen();
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Wrong User ID or Password";
        getch();
        initscreen();
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: 1. if You start project in C++, use C++ strings etc. Seems many uninitialised data is here. 2. Hard to debug mixed non-standard visual library (clrscr, getch etc) and standard streams.

Comment: why are you using `C` functions and not their objectively better `C++` counterparts?

Comment: @JanNilsFerner **objectively** better C++ counterparts - I sense a pun there :)

Comment: Care to elaborate? (I've been taught to a very limited scope)

Comment: @MayankGupta everywhere you use text, you should use `std::string` instead of plain char arrays. I'm gonna write you an example.

Comment: If OP means the 25-year-old flavour of Turbo C++, it didn't have `std::string`

Comment: I think turbo C++ have string, but no namespace. try using just `string`. There are also templates, but no `typename` keyword, just `class`.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use `fin.eof()` to detect when you've reached the end of the file. That's not what it's for. It lets you know when you've read past the end of file. As a result `while (!fin.eof())` will return the last item read twice.

Comment: I know, I just thought it won't make a difference

Comment: @MayankGupta: You've not only been taught to a limited scope, but to an antiquated level. 1989's Turbo C++, running on a DOS emulator, is _not_ fit for purpose in 2016. It wasn't fit for purpose in 1998, when C++ was standardised. Now, that's not really your fault, but you should at least be aware of the severe limitations of the course you're taking. You are going to have to relearn a lot of things when you get out of school and start work.

Comment: I've made some edits. What's wrong now?

Comment: @MayankGupta I realized you're using turbo c++. Unfortunatly, this limits my ability to help you drastically. For your own sake, don't trust whatever course you're taking right now. I think you may have to relearn pretty much everything.

Comment: @MayankGupta Maybe [this link](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/124194/user-registration-and-login-program) will be of help to you. The accepted answer should give you a good idea on how to realize your task in a modern way

Comment: Apparently, there is a problem with the password system, on removing it and using the username alone, it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using instead of `strcmp`, the function `strncmp`. This will ensure that you are comparing at max `n` characters and in case there is any junk ahead in the character array, it will not be compared. [Documentation of strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/).

In addition to that, using `gets` is unsafe, consider using [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead.

```
 int checkuser(char u[20])
    {
        return(strncmp(u,username, strlen(username)));
    }
    int checkpass(char p[20])
    {
        return(strncmp(p,pass1, strlen(pass));
    }
```

Comment: note that using `strncmp` like this will successfully match a partial subset of string

Comment: Or, since you're writing C++, use the proper facilities rather than medieval magic from the dark ages

Comment: yeah, OP has mixed his code quite a bit..i am wondering why he used gets() instead of cin.get() or something close..